# django custom field - how to modify another field's value

Tags: python, django

i am developing a django custom field . Inside the custom field def, how can i write some code that saves another field ? For example, inside the def of custom field, I have written pre_save method but after assigning values to other model fields, I have called model_instance.save() method but that resulted in an infinite loop. Can you tell me how to do this ?

```
class FullNameField(models.CharField):

    def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name):  
        firstname_field = models.CharField(
                null=True, blank=True, max_length=50)
        lastname_field = models.CharField(
                null=True, blank=True, max_length=50)

        firstname_field.creation_counter = self.creation_counter  
        lastname_field.creation_counter = self.creation_counter  

        cls.add_to_class('firstname', firstname_field )  
        cls.add_to_class('lastname', lastname_field )  

        super(FullNameField, self).contribute_to_class(cls, name)
```

The above code successfully creates the new fields firstname and lastname during syncdb, wha t i want to do is, when i populate the fullnamefield, firstname and lastname should also be populated. This fullname logic is just an example, but the requirement is same.

Comment: Please show your code. From your description it is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Whenever I populate a custom field, the code behind this custom field creates some extra fields dynamically . It is fine. At the same time, I want to populate the created extra fields , but couldnt do that.How can i do that ?

Comment: Please show your code and/or fragments of it and explain what you are trying to do. Your last comment only adds more confusion to this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`pre_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save) signal to get notified when the class is saved.

Add this to your `contribute_to_class` method:

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save

def populate_fullname(sender, instance, raw, **kwargs):
    if raw:
        return # be nice to syncdb
    fullname = u'%s %s' %  (instance.firstname, instance.lastname))
    setattr(instance, name, fullname)

pre_save.connect(populate_fullname, cls)
```